# extract text from xml elements using awk

Tags: regex, xml, awk

I've a file with ~ 10k of this type of xml tag:

```
<!-- http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/HP_0100516 -->

<owl:Class rdf:about="http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/HP_0100516">
    <obo:IAO_0000115 rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">The presence of a neoplasm of the ureter.</obo:IAO_0000115>
    <oboInOwl:created_by rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">doelkens</oboInOwl:created_by>
    <oboInOwl:creation_date rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">2010-12-20T10:35:11Z</oboInOwl:creation_date>
    <oboInOwl:hasDbXref rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">UMLS:C0041955</oboInOwl:hasDbXref>
    <oboInOwl:hasRelatedSynonym rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Neoplasia of the ureters</oboInOwl:hasRelatedSynonym>
    <oboInOwl:hasRelatedSynonym>ureter, cancer of</oboInOwl:hasRelatedSynonym>
    <oboInOwl:id rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">HP:0100516</oboInOwl:id>
    <rdfs:label rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Neoplasm of the ureter</rdfs:label>
</owl:Class>
<owl:Axiom>
    <owl:annotatedSource rdf:resource="http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/HP_0100516"/>
    <owl:annotatedProperty rdf:resource="http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/IAO_0000115"/>
    <owl:annotatedTarget rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">The presence of a neoplasm of the ureter.</owl:annotatedTarget>
    <oboInOwl:hasDbXref rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">HPO:probinson</oboInOwl:hasDbXref>
</owl:Axiom>
```

and I want to convert to a tab delimited text file with only 2 of the xml elements:

```
Neoplasm of the ureter  The presence of a neoplasm of the ureter
```

By using **awk**.

The text I need extract is within these tags:

```
<obo:IAO_0000115 rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">The presence of a neoplasm of the ureter.</obo:IAO_0000115>
```

and

```
<rdfs:label rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Neoplasm of the ureter</rdfs:label>
```

and the awk script I plan to use:

```
BEGIN{RS="//"}
{
  match($0, regex1 , a)
  match($0, regex2, b)
  print a[1], "\t", b[1]
}
```

What's the best way to use regex to obtain the text inside the xml elements?

*NOTE: this approach has been very useful and demonstrates that awk can be used to extract xml text from complex xml/rdf structures*

the final awk script used thanks to @RavinderSingh13:

```
awk '
/obo:IAO_0000115 rdf:datatype/ && match($0,/>.*</,a){
  gsub(/^>|<$/,"",a[0])
  
}
/rdfs:label rdf:datatype/ && match($0,/>.*</,b){
  gsub(/^>|<$/,"",b[0])
  print b[0]"\t"a[0]
}
'  file.xml > output.txt
```

Comment: The *best* way is to use XSLT or XML-aware tools instead of trying to hack up something with regular expressions.

Comment: could you please do let me know if you want to get values only for tags `obo:IAO_0000115` and `rdfs:label`? BTW its recommended by experts to use xmlatrlet xml related tools but if you can't install them then we could go ahead with `awk` solutions, kindly confirm the same once.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 yes prefer awk solution using tags shown

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you please try following, based on your shown samples only. Also `awk` is not an ideal tool for xml parsing since OP mentioned specifically OP can't use any other tools so going with this approach here.

```
awk '
(/obo:IAO_0000115 rdf:datatype/ || /rdfs:label rdf:datatype/) && match($0,/>.*</){
  print substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-2)
}
'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                                         ####Starting awk program from here.
(/obo:IAO_0000115 rdf:datatype/ || /rdfs:label rdf:datatype/) && match($0,/>.*</){    ####Chcecking condition if line contains obo:IAO_0000115 rdf:datatype OR rdfs:label rdf:datatype AND matches everythig from > to till < in current line.
  print substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-2)         ####Printing sub-string from RSTART to till RLENGTH here, where RSTART and RLENGTH variables are set whenever a match function has TRUE/matched regex in it.
}
'  Input_file                                 ####Mentioning Input_file here.
```

***From `man awk`:***

> RSTART      The index of the first character matched by match(); 0 if
> no match.  (This implies that character indices start at one.) RLENGTH
> The length of the string matched by match(); -1 if no match.

---

---

***EDIT:*** Adding 1 more solution as per OP's comment in case someone wants to create 2 different arrays out of 2 different string searches then try following. Written and tested in GNU `awk`.

```
awk '
/obo:IAO_0000115 rdf:datatype/ && match($0,/>.*</,a){
  gsub(/^>|<$/,"",a[0])
  print a[0]
}
/rdfs:label rdf:datatype/ && match($0,/>.*</,b){
  gsub(/^>|<$/,"",b[0])
  print b[0]
}
'  Input_file
```